# "Header.php" file is not visible on XAMPP

Tags: xampp

I have a problem with XAMPP latest version, it's the first time I use it, I've always used EasyPHP.

In the "include" directory of my site I have a file called "header.php", when I browse that folder from localhost, the file is not shown in the file list (directory index), if I browse it directly using `http://127.0.0.1/includes/header.php` it works, but if I browse `http://127.0.0.1/includes/` without the file name it's not shown in the directory index.

If I rename it to "pippo.php" I can see it in the directory index. I think it's a protected or particular name that Apache does not show for security.

With EasyPHP I see the file, so I think it's an Apache issue on XAMPP.

What should I set up to see all the files on XAMPP?

I can not find anything about it in Google or in forums. It is not extremely necessary, but as a developer if I browse a directory from "localhost" I want to see all of its contents.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your post to improve spelling as it seems that people wasn't understanding your real problem

Answer (score 0):

```
 "http://127.0.0.1/includes/header.php"
```

its mean you manually run `header.php` file

```
 "http://127.0.0.1/includes/"
```

if you not pass your file name it will run `index.php` or `index.html` file of `includes folder`  if
available otherwise blank page will be there

so you run `header.php` file so you manually pass the file name in `url` like
you first do

```
 "http://127.0.0.1/includes/header.php"
```

Comment: As I understand the problem the OP has is that the file doesn't appear in the Apache directory index that is shown when you don't have an index file (bad in production but useful in test environments).